# SQL Query fails on empty result

Tags: sql, delphi, select

I have a function that performs a query on a SQL database with an ADO connection, it is simply designed to provide a single result for a database entry that can only have one match for a `SELECT` type of query (i.e. get me the x value from ID 45, where there is and can only be one ID 45 entry).

The function works fine, until I hit a query that returns no results. The query just hangs, and the application cannot continue. Here is an example query string:

```
'SELECT Cost FROM MaterialCost ' +
'WHERE MaterialType = ''' + 'MS' +
''' AND Thickness = ''' + '0.250' + '''';
```

Again this exact string will work fine until I maybe query for something that I know before hand doesn't exist, which should return null or an empty string. Here is the function:

```
function SelectOneQuery(AQueryString : String; AADOConnectionString : String) : String;
var
  ADOQuery: TADOQuery;
begin
  //Create empty ADO Query, then connect to connection string
  ADOQuery := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  ADOQuery.ConnectionString:=AADOConnectionString;

  ADOQuery.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery.SQL.Add(AQueryString);
  ADOQuery.ExecSQL;

  ADOQuery.Open;

  //Set first query result and return first result
  ADOQuery.First;
  if(ADOQuery.Fields.Count > 0) then begin
    result:=ADOQuery.Fields[0].Value;
  end
  else begin
    result := '';
  end;
end;
```

I added the fields count thing, but I'm not sure if that's helping at all. Basically, if there are no result, i want `result := ''`

Comment: Why don't you know whether that addition helped? Where did the program hang before you added it, and where does it hang now? Use your debugger to identify which line of code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code snippet:

- The main problem is that you are checking `FieldCount`. `FieldCount` will always be nonzero because it contains the number of columns your query returns, regardless of the fact your query returned records or not. One option is to check `RecordCount` which represents the number of rows returned but a better option is to check   [`EOF`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Eof) flag.
- you are leaking ADOQuery. Always use `try/finally` blocks to create and cleanup objects.
- `ExecSQL` is used for queries that don't return recordsets (like INSERT and DELETE),
  use `Open` instead
- No need to use `First` after `Open`
- If you use the same query over and over you are better off using parameters, as a bonus your code will be more readable.

Example:

```
ADOQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Cost FROM MaterialCost WHERE MaterialType = :MaterialType AND Thickness = :Thickness';
ADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByname('MaterialType').Value := 'MS';
ADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByname('Thickness').Value := 0.25;
```

Your function code should be something like this:

```
function SelectOneQuery(const AQueryString, AADOConnectionString: string): string;
var
  ADOQuery: TADOQuery;
begin
  Result := '';

  ADOQuery := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    ADOQuery.ConnectionString := AADOConnectionString;
    ADOQuery.SQL.Text := AQueryString;
    ADOQuery.Open;
    if not ADOQuery.EOF then
      Result := ADOQuery.Fields[0].AsString;
  finally
    ADOQuery.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: not sure which change exactly corrected the problem, but i took your advice(s) so thanks it seems to work now.

Comment: This answer is quite "scattered". Exact fix for OPs problem was a replacement of ridiculous check for `FieldCount <> 0` (columns, whaat?) by the proper check for `RecordCount <> 0` (== `not EOF`, _rows_).

Comment: @FreeConsulting, actually, when you open a dataset, the cursor is set to the beginning. And if it's also the `EOF`, there's no record. But you're right, `RecordCount` could be more straightforward here. Also might be a small optimization to return `AsString` result instead of variant assignment.

Comment: @TLama, my point was: OP confused `RecordCount` with `FieldCount` and hence the bug, check out the original code snippet.

Comment: @FreeConsulting, ah, sorry. I've overlooked that. I thought you disagree with `EOF`. I need a break :-)

Comment: For @ikathegreat: Just for reference: [TDataSet.Eof documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Eof). Note particularly the second item in the list, and the "Tip" near the bottom.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: The reason why I don't use Recordcount is because accessing Recordcount will cause a fetch of all records in certain scenarios and sometimes this is not desired.

Comment: Personally I'd recommend use of EOF or the DataSet.IsEmpty function as some DBs have issues returning the RecordCount. I've had a weird problem in production code before now where RecordCount <> 0 on an empty dataset.

Comment: @MattAllwood, this depends on the used cursor type. For example with dynamic cursors, Recordcount is unknown beforehand and will be -1.

Comment: @whosrdaddy - The odd thing in that case was that IIRC the value wasn't -1, it was a strange +ve value. It was a while ago, so I may be mistaken, though. Still, if you need to support multiple DB servers (via ADOConnection for instance) Delphi/ADO can change the cursor type for you if the DB doesn't support the one you originally wanted, so it's safer to use EOF which works on all of them. The servers we use are Oracle and MSSQL, but could have been a dodgy provider.